# Requires the minimum valid row ratio reaches 0.50 to train a model, while got ratio 0.096547

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I am trying GCP AutoML to training and testing.
I received below error:

*Requires the minimum valid row ratio reaches 0.50 to train a model, while got ratio 0.096547.*

anyone pls help me o understand whats this means ?